# i want the ship/image to move on 'a' or 'd' press , and it works but the speed is greatly increased when moving from any where besides the corners

Tags: javascript, html, css

if the ship/image is in middle the speed of movement is very fast but from corner to corner the speed is smooth and exactly what I want any fix?

The image id is ship.

I wanted to increment the vw of the ship by 1 to give the illusion of movement.
if any one knows better code of what I'm trying please share, it would help me out a lot.

Thank you

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Space Game Engine    
</title>
    <style>
      
        #ship{
            position:absolute;
            top:40vw;
            left:45vw;
            width:8%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src='solo.png' id='ship'>
<script>
    const ship=document.getElementById('ship');
    var position=45;
    keylogger={};
    clickingAvaibility=true;//so that request animation frame run once for one key press.
    window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){

    keylogger[e.key]=true;// this means on pressing a key keylogger['a']=true
    if(clickingAvaibility==true){ 
    keyrunner();
    }
    clickingAvaibility=false;//resetted to false becomes true on keyup
});



window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
keylogger[e.key]=false;
clickingAvaibility=true;

});

function keyrunner(){
 var raf=requestAnimationFrame(keyrunner);
if(keylogger['d']==true){
        if(position<91 && keylogger['d']){
        ++position;
            
        ship.style.left=position+'vw';
        }
    else{
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    }
        }

if(keylogger['a']==true){
        if(position>1 && keylogger['a']){
        --position;
            ship.style.left=position+'vw';
           }
    else{
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    }
        
        }
}
            
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd imagine the units you are using when adding to position is causing at least part of the problem. Try wth `px` instead.